# Prove $\vdash (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow (( \lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B)$

Tags: logic

Give a hilbert style proof

$$ \vdash (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow (( \lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B)$$

How could I prove it ? When I apply deduction theorem, do I take $ ((\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow ( \lnot B \rightarrow A)) $ as a whole and move it to the left side because the parentheses or I can split it and do it like the following :

$$ (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A ) , (\lnot B \rightarrow A ) \vdash B$$

Lists of axioms and theorems.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Question I feel silly asking: What is the $\vdash$ symbol?

Comment: @Jedediyah It means that the statement on the right of $\vdash$ is a syntactic consequence (that is, you can find a formal a proof) of the set of premisses on the left of $\vdash$, in this case, the empty set.

Comment: @Tennisman You're not supposed to use the deduction theorem. You're being asked to give a formal proof.

Comment: No I can use whatever I want. The question didn't give any conditions. Also that is a part of the question. Another part asks to give proof by resolution which needs using deduction theorem.

Comment: @Tennisman It specifically says *give a Hilbert style proof*, to me this means it is asking for a formal proof.

Comment: @Tennisman Do you mind listing the axioms?

Comment: @GitGud See the edit please :)

Comment: @Tennisman I removed the predicate calculus shots since they have nothing to do with this. Can you also add the deduction rules?

Comment: As in "Mathematical Logic" by Tourlakis, 2.6.1 Metatheorem. (Deduction theorem) If $ \Gamma \cup {A} \vdash B$ , then also $ \Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B $.  $ \Gamma $ (Gamma) is a set of formulae.

Comment: @Tennisman Your citation demonstrated Git Gud's point.  It classifies it as a metatheorem.  If you're using a metatheorem, then you're not giving a Hilbert style proof, or equivalently *formal* proof which happens in the object logic.  The deduction metatheorem tells you that a formal proof exists (and its meta-proof tells you how to find a formal proof), but it doesn't actually exhibit a formal proof.

Comment: One last comment : the original formula of the exercise was : $(\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow  B$; you have inserted the missing parentheses in the wrong way ; it must be : $(\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow ((\lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow  B)$. See page 16 : "We say that all connectives are *right associative*."

Comment: Yeah I know when we have connectives with the same priority we start from the right. But the question was in a final exam and it was exactly like what I wrote. Let's say there is no mistake and  it's like this $((\lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A)) $, shouldn't we move it as a whole to the left side when applying *deduction theorem*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, we can use **2.4.11 Theorem** : $\vdash B \rightarrow A \equiv \lnot B \lor A$ [page 70] and using **2.4.4 Theorem** (*Double Negation*) : $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \equiv A$ [page 67] (and *Leibniz*) to have :

> $\vdash (\lnot B \rightarrow A) \equiv (B \lor A)$.

In the same way :

> $\vdash (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \equiv (B \lor \lnot A)$.

Now we apply **2.5.5 Corollary** : $A \lor B, \lnot A \lor B \vdash B$ [page 80], to get :

> > $(\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A), (\lnot B \rightarrow A) \vdash B$.

**Ex 20**, page 109, ask to prove it using "the deduction theorem and resolution"; this means to apply, after the two initial transformations, **2.5.4 Theorem** (*Cut Rule*) [page 79] : $A \lor B, \lnot A \lor C \vdash B \lor C$.

In this way, we get :

> > $(\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A), (\lnot B \rightarrow A) \vdash B \lor B$.

The result follows by **Idempotency of** $\lor$ [page 43] and with the application of the *Deduction Theorem* twice :

> $\vdash (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow ((\lnot B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B) $.