# Is $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B \land C) \rightarrow (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B) $ an absolute theorem schema?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B \land C) \rightarrow (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B) $ an absolute theorem schema ?

- If you think 'yes', then give a proof.
- If you think 'no', construct a counter model or prove the invalid strong generalization from it.

I wanna make sure if my answer is right.

---

What I have tried :

Yes!

By deduction theorem , $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B \land C) \vdash (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B)$

(1) $(\forall x)(A \rightarrow B \land C) $ (hypothesis)

(2) $ A \rightarrow (B \land C) $ (1, spec)

(3) $\lnot A \lor (B \land C)$ (2, 2.4.11 + Eqn)

(4) $(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \lor C)$ (3, 2,4,23(i) + Eqn)

(5) $(\lnot A \lor B)$ (4, split)

(6) $ A \rightarrow B$ (5, 2.4.11 + Eqn)

(7) $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B)$  (6 + Weak generaliztion , x dnof in $\Gamma$ )

See George Tourlakis, Mathematical Logic (2008) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752145/prove-vdash-lnot-b-rightarrow-lnot-a-rightarrow-lnot-b-rightarrow-a) for a lists of theorems and axioms.

Comment: This isn't an answer but hopefully it will be helpful for future questions: When trying to figure out if what you have is a theorem or not, try to figure out what is being said instead of trying to manipulate the symbols. e.g. in this example; fix an $x$. Now if A is true, then $B\wedge{C}$ is true. So assume $A$ is true. Then $B\wedge{C}$ is true. So what can you say about the truth value of $B$?

Comment: @DanulG - your semantic argument is *sound*, but we have to know how to interpret the statement of the problem : "is it a theorem schema ? If you think 'yes', then give a proof." We may show that it is a *valid* formula and then apply *completenss* **or** we must supply a *derivation* in the proof system (i.e.using axioms and rules of inference allowed in the system). This "decision" is OP's responsibility...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was trying to give OP the tools necessary to determine whether it was a theorem schema or not on his own. He seems to have figured it out properly but seems unsure. By "try to figure out what is being said instead of trying to manipulate the symbols", I don't mean "don't come up with a formal proof". It is meant to be interpreted as, figure out what the symbols say and hence, is it possible for this to be a theorem schema? That should help guide you to the correctness of your assertions. So you know whether a proof is possible or not after that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is my proof correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, DanulG's comment gives you the needed *hint* : the formula is *valid*; thus, by *completeness* is provable.

Your proof is sound.

Another proof can be "manufactured" starting from the fact that :

> $\vDash_{TAUT} (A \rightarrow (B \land C)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$

[easy check with truth-table].

Then apply **4.2.1 Definition (Logical Axiom Schemata of Predicate Logic)** [page 139] : **Ax1** : *partial generalization* of tautologies are axioms, to have :

> $\vdash (\forall x)[(A \rightarrow (B \land C)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)]$.

Finally, apply **Ax3** : all formulae of the form $(\forall x)(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((\forall x)A \rightarrow (\forall x)B)$ are axioms, and *modus ponens* to get :

> > $\vdash (\forall x)(A \rightarrow (B \land C)) \rightarrow (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B)$.

Comment: I didn't understand How did you move from step 2 to final step ? How did you apply **Ax3** and *modus ponens* ? Also is my proof not correct ?

Comment: @Tennisman - step 2 to last : write the **Ax3** as : $⊢(∀x)[(A→(B∧C))→(A→B)] \rightarrow [(∀x)(A→(B∧C))→(∀x)(A→B)]$; it is *clearly* of the "form" : $(∀x)(\alpha → \beta ) → ((∀x) \alpha → (∀x) \beta)$. Step 2 is the antecedent; thus, use it to "detach" the consequebt with *mp*.