# Give an equational proof $ \vdash p \land (q \equiv p) \equiv p \land q $

Tags: logic

Give an equational proof of $$ \vdash p \land (q \equiv p) \equiv p \land q $$

How can I give equational proof for this formula ?

See George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752145/prove-vdash-lnot-b-rightarrow-lnot-a-rightarrow-lnot-b-rightarrow-a) for a list of axioms and theorems.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I don't know where to start.

Comment: I would suggest not putting up the all of these rules because it just makes this more crowded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*.

Start with :

> $(q \equiv p) \equiv (q \rightarrow p) \land (p \rightarrow q)$ --- (2.4.26)

and then :

> $(q \equiv p) \equiv (\lnot q \lor p) \land (\lnot p \lor q)$ --- by (2.4.11)

to obtain :

> > $[p \land (q \equiv p)] \equiv p \land [(\lnot q \lor p) \land (\lnot p \lor q)]$.

Then apply *Associativity of* $\land$ to the RHS and go on with the usual transformations, according to the rules you have in your list, until you reach the goal.